# Doing PBEWithMD5AndDES (java) in UWP

Tags: c#, cryptography, uwp

I am fairly new to c# and UWP development. I have a web API that sends passwords encrypted with PBEWithMD5AndDES. I need to decrypt the password on UWP side. I have looked at [CodeProject PBEWithMD5AndDES .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16450/Emulating-PBEWithMD-AndDES-Encryption-under-NET) and a couple of other posts but all of that is not applicable for UWP. I have looked at some other posts too [RSA UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36461380/uwp-universal-windows-platform-rsa-asymmetrickeyalgorithmprovider-import-publi). But due to my limited experience with C# and Cryptography, in general, I am not able to convert the code project example into a UWP solution. 
 I have found this library [Portable Bouncy Casale](https://libraries.io/nuget/Portable.BouncyCastle) that allows PBEWithMD5AndDES in C# but with no tutorial, I can't seem to figure out how it works.
 Any small example of this code project implementation in UWP or library usage would be appreciated.
 Thanks

Comment: I need to decrypt the password on the Mobile side.

Comment: I need to encrypt + decrypt on the client side. The encryption on the API side can't be changed. So when I receive a normal http response (XML) on my client. I need to decrypt the password in the response XML and encrypt it again to send it somewhere else.

Comment: I know the issues with encryption. Key sharing, Confidentiality, Authenticity etc etc. I believe my question is pretty simple, I just need to decrypt and then encrypt using PBEWithMD5AndDES which is available in java. How can do the same in UWP.

Answer (score 1):

The official sample [Cryptography and Certificate sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Cryptography-and-3305467b) provides how to encrypt and decrypt data with winrt APIs. As you are using `PBEWithMD5AndDES`, you can find the  `DES Symmetric Algorithm`  encrypt and decrypt and `MD5 Hash Algorithm` scenarios in the sample which are what you want. This sample target windows 8.1, which is also suit for uwp app. I also helped you transfer it to uwp app if you needed you can [download](https://github.com/sunteenwu/CCryptographic) for using.

As far as I known, `Password-based encryption with MD5AndDes` is not a new algorithm. It is built with `MD5` and `DES`. So for directly decrypt the password in your client, please combine the algorithms by yourself since I don't know how you encrypt with `MD5` and `DES` on your server side.  For example, if you only use [`DES_CBC`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.symmetricalgorithmnames.descbc.aspx) symmetric algorithm on the server side, you will decrypt by `DES-CBC`. If you use `MD5` hash algorithm and then `DES-CBS`, you will need to decrypt by `DES-CBC` firstly, and then use `MD5` hash algorithm  to encrypt your client password to compare with the decrypted result by `DES`.

More details please reference [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.cryptographicengine.aspx).